# Python Pandas Problem Adding Rows with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I wanted to add columns to a dataframe, with unique names. I tried to do that automatically with a for loop. I added an index after the name, but only the last value of **i** got displayed. I am relatively new to python and need help! Thanks!

My Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import numpy as np
import csv
import time


key = ''

product = 'ENCHANTED_RAW_CHICKEN'
url = 'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar/product?key=' + key + '&productId=' + product
url2 = 'https://api.hypixel.net/gameCounts?key=' + key

for i in range(3):
    json_obj = urlopen(url)
    json_obj2 = urlopen(url2)
    all_data = json.load(json_obj)
    gameCounts = json.load(json_obj2)

    product_info = all_data['product_info']
    week_historic = product_info['week_historic']
    games = gameCounts['games']
    skyblock = (games['SKYBLOCK'])
    skyblock_players = skyblock['players']

    with open('DATA_' + str(product) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(week_historic, outfile)

    df = pd.read_json (r'DATA_' + product + '.json')
    df.to_csv (r'CSV' + product + '.csv', index = None)

    df = pd.read_csv(r'CSV' + product + '.csv', encoding='utf-8')
    df = df.drop('productId', 1)
    player_count = 'playercount' + str(i)
    df[player_count]= df.shape[0] * [skyblock_players]
    #time.sleep(10)
print(df)
df.to_csv (r'CSV' + product + '.csv', index = None)
```

Output:

```
timestamp  nowBuyVolume  ...  sells  playercount2
0    2020-03-19 16:46:45.517         45806  ...    248         33202
1    2020-03-19 17:16:45.517         45576  ...    176         33202
2    2020-03-19 17:46:45.517         47132  ...    121         33202
3    2020-03-19 17:59:31.600         38251  ...      0         33202
4    2020-03-19 18:29:31.579         33466  ...     31         33202
..                       ...           ...  ...    ...           ...
335  2020-03-26 14:55:49.357        159465  ...    168         33202
336  2020-03-26 15:25:49.357        157919  ...     92         33202
337  2020-03-26 15:55:49.357        133332  ...     79         33202
338  2020-03-26 16:25:49.357        130275  ...    139         33202
339  2020-03-26 16:28:29.379        130146  ...     16         33202
```

How I would want to like the output:

```
timestamp  nowBuyVolume  ...  sells  playercount0  playercount1  playercount2
0    2020-03-19 16:46:45.517         45806  ...    248         33200         33201         33202
```

My csv:

```
timestamp,nowBuyVolume,nowSellVolume,buyCoins,buyVolume,buys,sellCoins,sellVolume,sells,playercount2
2020-03-19 17:46:45.517,47132,105049,3629664.7,3978,96,3727318.6000000034,3767,121,34537
```

Comment: I guess you have several delimiters in your csv. You can set the delimiters in `df.to_csv (r'CSV' + product + '.csv', sep='\t\s')`, as a regex. Replace the values of sep with your various delimiters.

Comment: I only have ',' as seperator. The problem is, that there is only playercount2 instead of playercount0, playercount1, playercount2. Also the delimiter must be a character string. Thanks tho

Comment: I understood that. My question si what do you have between "248" and "33202" in the first line, for example? The value between them should be either transformed into ',', or considered as a separator and included among the values of sep. You can manage the column names afterwards.

Comment: I added the csv file below

Comment: Which csv is that? Input or output?

Comment: That is the csv output file that is created. There is no input file, as I get my data through an API

Comment: Of course it is.You instantiate your dataframe in the loop. Where do you take your data in `playercount0`, `playercount1`, etc. from ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your error is that you instantiate in the loop the first part of your DataFrame.

I suppose the first par of the DataFrame is in `url` and the second part in `url2`

You should do, first of all :

```
json_obj = urlopen(url)
all_data = json.load(json_obj)
product_info = all_data['product_info']
week_historic = product_info['week_historic']
with open('DATA_' + str(product) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(week_historic, outfile)

df = pd.read_json (r'DATA_' + product + '.json')
df.to_csv (r'CSV' + product + '.csv', index = None)

df = pd.read_csv(r'CSV' + product + '.csv', encoding='utf-8')

json_obj2 = urlopen(url2)
gameCounts = json.load(json_obj2)
games = gameCounts['games']
skyblock = (games['SKYBLOCK'])
skyblock_players = skyblock['players']

N = 3
for i in range(N):
    player_count = 'playercount' + str(i)
    df[player_count]= # search in skyblock_players or wherever you want the data for each column
```

Comment: I want the playercount0 to playercount3 to be added automatically depending on how many iterations I have

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah that line was not needed, but it doesn´t matter. I basically use an API and want to get the newest data appended to an csv as playercount x + 1, so I can afterwards analyse the csv. I want the program to store the variable skyblock_players every 30 Minutes and add it to the csv. This is how the csv should look like:

Comment: The Constant doesnt affect my problem

Comment: Yes it does, you mentioned yourself that you want to add columns automatically depending on the number of your iterations. If you set it to 3, it will not be dynamic. You should mention also where do you take the information in each iteration from. I suppose in url2 ?

Comment: I need the data to refresh it self in each iterations. If I do it your way it will always have the same value

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I updated the answer. If you do like that, at each iteration you add a new column. No, you do not have the same answer, if you do like that, but you must decide what do you fill in a column in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much!